# Can't find variable in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sqlite, redux

I'm trying to adapt a tutorial to my own "Photo making app". But I somehow struggle to implement SQLite into my project and I don't understand the Error and why I'm getting it.

I'm having the following reducer:

```
import { ADD_PHOTO, SET_OBJECTS } from "./photo-actions";
import PhotoObject from "../models/photoObject";

const initialState = {
  photos: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_OBJECTS:
      return {
        objects: action.objects.map(
          (ob) => new Object(ob.id.toString(), ob.title, ob.imageUri)
        ),
      };
    case ADD_PHOTO:
      const newObject = new PhotoObject(
        action.photoData.id,
        action.photoData.title,
        action.photoData.image,
        action.photoData.description
      );
      console.log("Ich bin das newObject aus photo-reducer.js");
      console.log(newObject);
      return {
        photos: state.photos.concat(newObject), //<---------this is where I assume the error
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The last bit of my error log looks as follows:

```
Ich bin das newObject aus photo-reducer.js
PhotoObject {
  "description": "cool",
  "id": 1,
  "imageUri": undefined,
  "title": "Dog",
}
In photo-actions.js--> addPhoto wurde dispatch ausgeführt

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: state //<----- it says it can't find the state but I'm sure I defined it correctly, didn't I?

This error is located at:
    in Gallery (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
```

this is my action

```
...

export const addPhoto = (title, image, description) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const fileName = image.split("/").pop();
    const newPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName;

    try {
      await FileSystem.moveAsync({
        from: image,
        to: newPath,
      });
      const dbResult = await insertObject(
        title,
        newPath,
        "dummyDescription aus photo-actions",
        "locationTest aus photo-actions",
        10
      );
      console.log("Ich bin das dbResult aus photo-actions.js-->addPhoto");
      console.log(dbResult);
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_PHOTO,
        photoData: {
          id: dbResult.insertId,
          title: title,
          imageUri: newPath,
          description: description,
        },
      });
      console.log("In photo-actions.js--> addPhoto wurde dispatch ausgeführt");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  };
};

export const loadObjects = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const dbResult = await fetchObjects();
      dispatch({ type: SET_OBJECTS, objects: dbResult.rows._array });
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
};
```

this is the component where I want to use the state in:

```
...
const Gallery = (props) => {
  const photos = useSelector((state) => state.photos.photos);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(objectActions.loadObjects());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={photos}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={(itemData) => (
...
```

the problem is started by using the expo ImagePicker and wanting to store the taken data:

```
...
  const savePhotoHandler = () => {
    dispatch(
      photosActions.addPhoto(titleValue, selectedImage, descriptionValue)
    );
    props.navigation.navigate("Gallery");<--------------this command leads to the component where I receive the error when I want to grab the state
  };
...
```

Comment: Based on your logs it looks like the error is happening after where you think.  It looks like the whole `addPhoto` goes through correctly.  Is there some other reference to `state` on the `Gallery` screen other than the one in `useSelector`?

Comment: I have found an error in your reducer which I will write an answer for, but I'm not sure how it relates to the specific error message "Can't find variable: state"

Answer (score 0):

#### Serializable State

It is [not a good idea](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) to store a non-serializable value like a `PhotoObject` class instance in state.  I would just store the raw data from the `action.payload` and construct it into a `PhotoObject` instance when you select it from the state.  Storing non-serializable objects will interfere with the Redux Dev Tools.

#### Returning Incomplete State

A reducer must always return a complete state.  Your `photos` reducer has two properties: `objects` and `photos`.  All of your cases are returning an object with only one property and removing the other.

```
return {
  objects: action.objects.map(
    (ob) => new Object(ob.id.toString(), ob.title, ob.imageUri)
  ),
};
```

```
return {
  photos: state.photos.concat(newObject),
};
```

You need to use `...state` to return the other properties which you are not updating.

#### new Object()

I have no idea what you are doing here:

```
new Object(ob.id.toString(), ob.title, ob.imageUri)
```

The [`Object` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object) only takes one argument.

I wonder if there's a bunch of typos in this code where you meant `new PhotoObject` and you also meant to set the property `photos` instead of `objects`?

Maybe this works?

```
const initialState = {
  photos: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_OBJECTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        photos: action.objects.map(
          ({id, title, imageUri}) => ({
            id: id.toString(),
            title,
            image: imageUri,
            description: ''
          })
        ),
      };
    case ADD_PHOTO:
      return {
        ...state,
        photos: state.photos.concat(action.photoData),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Linda Paiste. Your answer gave me valuable feedback. I actually did as you said made a lot of typos but my mistake ultimately was to console.log(state.photos.photos) in my component. To be honest I cutted that part out so you couldn't solve it.

Tl;dr: You cannot console.log an redux internal state inside a component. I hope this makes my mistake clear.